# Understanding r.js options w/grunt & backbone and relative paths

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, gruntjs, r.js

I'm trying to figure out how to use r.js. I keep getting errors thrown such a module path does not exist, or files getting dumped where they shouldn't be.

I've got a single page application that is integrated with wordpress. I've adopted [this backbone boilerplate](https://github.com/BoilerplateMVC/Backbone-Require-Boilerplate)  for my general structure, although I've set things up quite different. My file structure is shown below.

```
.Theme Folder
├── _assets
|   ├── _application
|   |   ├── css
|   |   ├── fonts
|   |   ├── img
|   |   ├── _js
|   |   |   ├── main.js  //this is my require.js config file
|   |   |   ├── _app  //here's where the boilerplate structure comes into play
|   |   |       ├── collections
|   |   |       ├── models
|   |   |       ├── routers
|   |   |       ├── templates
|   |   |       ├── views
|   |   |   ├── libs
|   |   |   ├── utilities
|   |   ├── scss
|   |   ├── video
|   └── build  //Concatenated application directory mirror
|   └── gruntfile.js
|   └── bower.json
|   └── package.json
```

To save the heartache of deciphering my gigantic grunt file. Basically I originally set it up so that everything gets conatenated, uglified, and compiled into the build folder. I created a simple task for r.js to just test things out. I get an error saying my lodash library cannot be found (first path in my main.js file). It thinks lodash is in assets/lodash.js it's ignoring my baseUrl property in my main.js (require.js configuration) it's actual location is assets/application/js/libs/lodash.js. My requirejs task is below:

```
        requirejs: {
          compile: {
            options: {
              baseUrl: "./",
              mainConfigFile: "application/js/main.js",
              name: "./application/js/main",
              out: "./build/js/optimized.js"
            }
          }
        }
```

I'm having the hardest time figuring out what exactly rjs is doing. When I expect it to work it's not looking for the files in the right directory. When I configure it to find the right files it copies my entire assets folder and dumps it into my build folder... Which has caused a lot of confusion as to what all r.js is doing and what it wants me to input for it's options.

This is the error I am currently getting:

```
>> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
>> 'path-to-theme-folder-here/assets/libs/lodash.js'
>> In module tree:
>>     application/js/main.min
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me with the description you give, this should work:

```
requirejs: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      baseUrl: "application/js/",
      mainConfigFile: "application/js/main.js",
      name: "main",
      out: "build/js/optimized.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, in the end I ended up pointing my baseurl and mainconfig to my build folder due to my main.js pointing to minified file names.. Thanks a bunch.