# Understanding r.js, almond, and relative paths

Tags: requirejs, r.js, almond

I see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350131/understanding-r-js-options-w-grunt-backbone-and-relative-paths) but AFAICT it's not working for me. Maybe I'm doing something stupid.

I'm using [almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond/) and [grunt-contrib-requirejs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs). I've tried a bunch of stuff

Here's my layout

```
.
├── Gruntfile.js
├── 3rdparty
│   ├── require.js
├── src
│   ├── lib.js
│   └── main.js
└── node_modules
    └── almond
        └── almond.js
```

And here's my grunt-contrib-requirejs config

```
requirejs: {
  full: {
    options: {
      baseUrl: "./",
      name: "node_modules/almond/almond.js",
      include: [ "src/main.js" ],
      out: "dist/app.js",
      optimize: "none",
    },
  },
},
```

main.js looks like this

```
requirejs(['./lib',], function(lib) {
  lib.hello();
});
```

lib.js looks like this

```
define([], function() {
    return {
      hello: function() {
          console.log("hello from lib");
      },
    };
});
```

If run a page that uses require.js as in

```
<script src="3rdparty/require.js" data-main="src/main.js"></script>
```

It runs great. [You can see it live it here](http://greggman.github.io/grunt-contrib-requirejs-example/test-before.html). Check the console and you'll see it prints `hello from lib`

So I run grunt. Then I run a page that uses `dist/app.js` and I get the error

```
Uncaught Error: undefined missing lib
```

Here's a [live page](http://greggman.github.io/grunt-contrib-requirejs-example/test-after.html).

Checking the generated `dist/app.js` I see lib has been turned into this

```
define('src/lib',[], function() {
   ...
});
```

And main is including it like this

```
requirejs(['./lib'], function(lib) {
  ...
});
```

In other words, the id that r.js generated `src/lib` doesn't match the id that main is referencing `./lib`.

This seems like a very straight forward example for r.js. Like practically "hello world".

What am I doing wrong?

One thing I've tried is changing the `baseUrl` to `./src`

```
requirejs: {
  full: {
    options: {
      baseUrl: "./src",
      name: "node_modules/almond/almond.js",
      include: [ "src/main.js" ],
      out: "dist/app.js",
      optimize: "none",
    },
  },
},
```

But now I get

```
{ [Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/gregg/temp/grunt-contrib-requirejs-example/src/node_modules/almond/almond.js'
    at Error (native)
]
  originalError: 
   { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/gregg/temp/grunt-contrib-requirejs-example/src/node_modules/almond/almond.js']
     errno: -2,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'open',
     path: '/Users/gregg/temp/grunt-contrib-requirejs-example/src/node_modules/almond/almond.js',
     fileName: '/Users/gregg/temp/grunt-contrib-requirejs-example/src/node_modules/almond/almond.js' } }
```

So I try fixing the almond path

```
requirejs: {
  full: {
    options: {
      baseUrl: "./src",
      name: "../node_modules/almond/almond.js",
      include: "main",
      out: "dist/app.js",
      optimize: "none",
    },
  },
},
```

But that fails as well

```
{ [Error: Error: ERROR: module path does not exist: ../node_modules/almond/almond.js for module named: ../node_modules/almond/almond.js. Path is relative to: /Users/gregg/temp/grunt-contrib-requirejs-example
    at /Users/gregg/temp/grunt-contrib-requirejs-example/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:30214:35
]
  originalError: [Error: ERROR: module path does not exist: ../node_modules/almond/almond.js for module named: ../node_modules/almond/almond.js. Path is relative to: /Users/gregg/temp/grunt-contrib-requirejs-example] }
```

What am I not getting?

[The entire thing is checked into github here](https://github.com/greggman/grunt-contrib-requirejs-example) if you'd like to work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here's the answer.

r.js prefers module names not paths

```
requirejs: {
  full: {
    options: {
      baseUrl: "./src",
      paths: {
        almond: "../node_modules/almond/almond",
      }
      name: "almond",
      include: [ "main.js" ],
      out: "dist/app.js",
      optimize: "none",
    },
  },
},
```